# Realm Array Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsarray, realm

Im currently develop a bookmark function in my app. The flow of this function is from the News list screen, user choose to read news, then in the WebView will contain a bookmark button. After the bookmark button is pressed, the news will be stored in Realm, then displayed in Bookmark ViewController. However, when i pushed into the BookmarkVc, app crashed with below exception:

[image]

I think the problem come from the ArticleList when it always contain only 1 element even if i added more. Thus it leads to the index out of range problem:

[image]

Here is my code for webViewVC and bookmark button action:

```
import UIKit
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class WebViewVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
var ulr:String?
let articleList = ArticleList()
var article:NewsArticle?
var list : Results<ArticleList>!
var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
250, height: 20))

func drawNavBarUI(navigationItem:UINavigationItem) {
 let bookmarkBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
 bookmarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "bookmark"), for: .normal)
 bookmarkBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
 let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favortie"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(saveFavoriteArticle))
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1,UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)], animated: true)
}

func saveFavoriteArticle() {
    articleList.articles.append(article!)
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(articleList)
    }
    print(articleList)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.loadHTMLString(ulr!, baseURL: nil)
    drawNavBarUI(navigationItem: self.navigationItem)
}
```

And for the BookmarkVC:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class BookmarksVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var list : Results<ArticleList> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(ArticleList.self)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BookmarkCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "bookmarkCell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return list.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let dict = list[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookmarkCell", for: indexPath) as! BookmarkCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = dict.articles[indexPath.row].title
    return cell

}
```

This is the first time i use Realm and tried for a whole time to figure out, but it still no work. So please any one can help me to solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: seems like you did it wrong on your `cellForRow`, print `list[indexPath.row]` and `dict.articles[indexPath.row]` see if it have anything

Comment: app crashed before the View appear, but i think the problem might came from the ArticleList object, its array always contain only 1 element

Comment: Log list count in numberOfRowsInSection method. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4248

Comment: It crash before view appear because you reload table from `viewDidLoad`, its not recommended though, make sure you subscript the array correctly, the error clearly said so, maybe change all `indexPath.row` to 0 and see if its still crashing or not

Comment: i changed the indexPath.row to 0 and it worked, thats why i said that the problem come from the array, whenever i added new element, it deleted the previous one, so the array always contain 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `dict.articles` List is empty when you subscript to get its `indexPath.row`'s object.